# Disabling transaction on spring testng test method

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, testng

I am using TestNG together with Spring and JPA. So far I am using to test database stuff my test class which extends `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests`. With `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)` everything works fine and I do not need to cary about cleanup. Spring creates a default transaction on the beginning of each of my test method which is than rollbacked. This is a very neat trick to solve famous "Transactional tests considered harmful" problem.

Unfortunately I need for one method in this class (one test) to not have this default transaction. This is because this test method simulates batch processing and I have multiple transactions inside it which are in production independent. The only way I was able to simulate and solve problem is to configure those inner transactions with `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` but this I do not want to have in production code. Is there some way to disable Spring transaction for my particular test method (so I do not need to use `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` but `Propagation.REQUIRED` in my service methods) ?

Comment: Move that code to another test class which isn't transactional. Earlier versions of the Spring Test framework had the `@NotTransactional` annotation but that has been deprecated and removed in favor of splitting transactional and non-transactional tests.

Comment: @M.Deinum unfortunatelly this will not easily work for me as i have some dependencies in it and I do not want to duplicate code, but I have found that invoking the test method in separate thread does what I want to. It seems to me, that Spring test transaction protection is only relevant for main thread, but when I invoke test method body in separate thread it will work as I want to. If somebody has better solution than my workaround - please post, otherwise I write whole solution as answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum correct tip, but IMHO Spring approach here is extremely inflexible and time-consuming for existing tests. **Tip to the future**: the best and the most flexible way for me is to abandon from the very beginning `@Transactional` and use the `TransactionTemplate` class. Since JDK 8 it's more convenient to use.

Comment: So instead of declarative transaction management you prefer to go back to the dark ages of manual transaction management, which is basically what you are doing.

Comment: Inside unit tests: **yes** - because it is the only correct way here. Declarative transaction management works perfectly in the production code, [not](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/spring-pitfalls-transactional-tests.html) inside unit tests.

Comment: @M.Deinum Agree with Grzesiek D. , for testing declarative transaction management is not as good as it sounds.

Comment: @M.Deinum, just for clarification: I recommended abandoning `@Transactional` in favour of letting the Spring manage transactions in its normal way. I mentioned `TransactionTemplate` only as a workaround for existing problems (like one mentioned by the OP). Of course, if we don't rollback then we have to take care of the cleaning a database before or after every test case.

Comment: It is a bad thing and makes you do more work without any actual benefit imho. If you have shared classes create a base test class, make 1 transactional and 1 not transactional. Pretty easy to do and understand and you can still use declarative transactions with all the benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that by executing the body of my test in separate thread prevent Spring from transaction. So the workaround solution is something like:

```
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = { test.SpringTestConfigurator.class })
    @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
    @Slf4j
    @WebAppConfiguration
    public class DBDataTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {    
    /**
     * Variable to determine if some running thread has failed.
     */
    private volatile Exception threadException = null;

   @Test(enabled = true)
    public void myTest() {
        try {
            this.threadException = null;
            Runnable task = () -> {
                myTestBody();
            };
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            executor.submit(task);
            executor.shutdown();
            while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
                if (this.threadException != null) {
                    throw this.threadException;
                }
            }
            if (this.threadException != null) {
                throw this.threadException;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Test has failed.", e);
            Assert.fail();
        }
    }

 public void myTestBody() {
    try {
        // test body to do
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       this.threadException = e; 
    } 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know you've already solved your problem, but for folks who will come here in the future...

Unfortunately it seems that there is no way to disable existing transaction inside test that uses `@Transactional` annotation.

IMHO Spring approach here is extremely inflexible. But there is a workaround for your problem. It would be enough to encapsulate needed logic inside Spring `TransactionTemplate` class. This would ensure that code in your test case would be launched inside a new transaction.

---

**Personal advice**: the best and the most flexible way from my point of view is to abandon from the very beginning `@Transactional` tests and setup database into known state **before** every test. In this way, Spring will manage transactions exactly the same way as in production.
No quirks, no hacks, no manual transaction management.

I know that using `@Transactional` with a "rollback" policy around unit tests is a tempting idea, but it has too many pitfalls. I recommend reading this article [Spring Pitfalls: Transactional tests considered harmful](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/spring-pitfalls-transactional-tests.html).

*Of course I don't complain here about @Transactional itself - because it greatly simplifies transaction management in the production code.*

Comment: Nice approach, will use in some other testing classes (I do not want to rewrite my testing now).

Comment: IMHO a hideous and unnecessary complex way of testing your code. Adding multi threading to a test or adding manual means of managing your  transactions is imho a sign you are doing something wrong in the first place. If you want a test to be non-transactional then make it non-transactional. I also find that one should use a different technology (plain JDBC) to verify your outcomes and not use the same technology one used to persist things, only then you truly test your database content. Who says JPA is hitting the database and not a (1st or 2nd lvl) cache?

Comment: @M.Deinum Hmm, I'm not convinced. The most popular way to ensure JPA is hitting the database is disabling 2nd level cache and letting the JPA normally commit transactions. In this way, using a different technology is not needed. Don't you agree?

Comment: @M.Deinum Is setting the database into known state a "hideous" and "unnecessary complex"? IMHO it is exactly the opposite. For a price of cleaning the database we got *no quirks, no hacks, no manual transaction management*. And code in tests behaves exactly as in production.

Comment: The test code threading is hideous and unnecessary complex. You have a hack because you introduced multi threading into your test case. You now also have tests polluting your database or you have to cleanup manually, eventually that will bite you somewhere as tests now can (and thus will) interfere with each other. Also regarding disabling 2nd level caching you still have the 1st level cache which you cannot disable and which can still bite you (you work around with the hack). When disabling caching you are chancing to much configuration to make your tests work and imho that is also bad.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry, but I cant agree. Disabling second level cache is simple as `<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />`.  And why disable 1st level cache, when plain "commit" is just enough? And it is obvious that tests which use a database, would interfere with each other when running simultaneously. Unit testing and database has a different nature (they are no longer **unit** but **integration**). That is why, such group of tests is being run sequentially.

Comment: @M.Deinum And about multi-threading: when application can be accessed by more than one user, then you have to do some multi-threading tests or stress tests. Have you always been skipping them?

Comment: And if you are running integration tests the configuration should mimic the production configuration. I don't say it isn't simple to disable 2nd lvl caching. I'm saying that it is a wrong thing to customize your configuration to suite your needs for testing. Then basically your tests are useless and provide no business value, they give you no guarantee that it works in real live, because well the config is different.

Comment: When setup correctly tests don't have to interfere with each other test should be independent, using shared state (that is what you basically do using a database) is dangerous as the outcome of one test can influence the other.

Comment: Running stress or load tests is something else as running a unit or integration test. And that, imho, has no place in either a unit or integration test. You use a system test for that and pounce it with a lot of concurrent users. You don't try to shoehorn that into a unit test as again that says nothing. Next to that I'm also a firm believer that doing a unit test for a dao isn't providing much value, you should use an integration test which provides business value. The exception could be a complex query creation part of the application.

Comment: @M.Deinum Finally I can agree. Word "integration test" was too broad for our discussion, as it's an umbrella for many kind of tests. Surely we have unit, integration, end-to-end, stress tests. Whereas unit can use mocks, I **believe** that basic integration tests can use slightly crafted/ customized configuration but still be as close as possible to the real application. That's  absolutely not allowed for the end-to-end and stress tests. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot >=2.1.5.RELEASE has the following solution.

> By default, data JPA tests are transactional and roll back at the end of each test. See the relevant section in the Spring Framework Reference Documentation for more details. If that is not what you want, you can disable transaction management for a test or for the whole class as follows:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class ExampleNonTransactionalTests {

}
```

(s. [Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test))